# Computing the Eigenvalue Spectrum of a Graph with Igraph

Tags: python, networkx, igraph

Is there a way, with Igraph in Python, to compute (to eventually plot) the Eigenvalue spectrum of a graph as described in the article?

http://lthiwww.epfl.ch/~leveque/Projects/barabasi_al.pdf

If so, which functions need be used? If not, what are some good alternative methods?

Comment: Isn't this just converting the graph into an adjacency matrix and then calculating the eigenvalues of the matrix?

Comment: Could be, I saw that network had a function to do it, but it coud indeed be overkill. I'll check in numpy then. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out ow to do it only with igraph:

```
import numpy.linalg
from igraph import *
import random
import numpy as np
import time

nbr_noeuds = 50
dens = .2

p=random.uniform(dens,dens)
G = Graph.Erdos_Renyi(nbr_noeuds, p, directed=False, loops=False)

t0 = time.time()
L = G.laplacian(normalized=True)
e = numpy.linalg.eigvals(L)
print time.time()-t0
```

And the computation is much faster too, the print output is 0.0009

Comment: Note that the *laplacian* matrix of a graph is different than the *adjacency* matrix, but it is is easy to convert between the two (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix). The paper you mentioned uses the eigenvalues of the *adjacency* matrix, not of the *laplacian* matrix.

Answer (score 1):

It's simpler and probably faster this way

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: from numpy.linalg import eigvals

In [3]: %timeit eigvals(nx.normalized_laplacian_matrix(nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(50,0.2)).A)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.13 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks! The issue is that I have an igraph graph to begin with, conversion takes a while, I think...